# google.script.run pass variable and get return in promise

Tags: google-apps-script, promise

Im puzzling how to get the return from a google.script.run while also passing variables to the run function.

My google script function is:

```html
function message(text) {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  cursor.insertText(text);
  return 'success';
}
```

while my sidebar script is:

```html
const p = func => new Promise(resolve=>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve)[func]()
  );
  
document.getElementById("wikindx-display-about").onclick = displayAbout;

 async function displayAbout() {
    await p('message');
 }
```

Im not sure how to gather 'success' from the gs script and I'm not sure how to send the variable text to message().

Answer (score 2):

#### Modified snippet

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).message("Hello")

function onSuccess(returnValue) {
    console.log(returnValue); // Will print "success"
    }
```

There is no need to wrap in promises or async (I believe its possible but its not necessary).

In the above example:

- `google.script.run` will send a request to Apps Script to run `message` with the argument `"Hello"`.
- This will insert the text as per your `message` function.
- `message` will `return 'success'`
- This return value will be sent back to the sidebar (client side), and then `withSuccessHandler` will use the return value as an argument to the function `onSuccess`.
- `onSuccess` just logs the return value from Apps Script.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Client Server Comms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)